# Spring Boot: existing object gets altered instead of a new created

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am stuck with a problem at a Spring Boot project. To take it short: I'm creating a photo archive and want to save multiple photos to each event. I created Photo and Event objects with annotations to use jpa/Hibernate. Also structured the project using repositories, services and controllers. Built a form to create the events. Index page shows all events plus button to upload a photo to the specific event.
And that's where the problem starts. I can create exactly one photo for each event despite I am creating a new Photo object at the controller and pass it to the Thymeleaf template for photo creation form. When filling the form again I am overwriting the data of the single existing photo and I have no clue why.

Photo Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "photographies")
public class Photo {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String label;

private String photographer;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private Event event;

//@Column(nullable = false)
private Blob image;

private Date date;

public Photo(){};

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public String getPhotographer() {
    return photographer;
}

public void setPhotographer(String photographer) {
    this.photographer = photographer;
}

public Event getEvent() {
    return event;
}

public void setEvent(Event event) {
    this.event = event;
}

public Blob getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(Blob image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public void assignEvent(Event event){
    this.event = event;
    event.getPhotos().add(this);
}

  @Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Photo photo = (Photo) o;
    return id == photo.id && Objects.equals(label, photo.label) && Objects.equals(photographer, photo.photographer) && Objects.equals(event, photo.event) && Objects.equals(image, photo.image) && Objects.equals(date, photo.date);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, label, photographer, event, image, date);
}
}
```

Event Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
public class Event {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

private String label;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "event", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Photo> photos = new LinkedList<>();

public Event(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public Event(){};
}

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Photo> photos = new LinkedList<>();

public Event(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public Event(){};

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public List<Photo> getPhotos() {
    return photos;
}

public void setPhotos(List<Photo> photos) {
    this.photos = photos;
}

public void addPhoto(Photo photo){
    photos.add(photo);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Event event = (Event) o;
    return id == event.id && Objects.equals(label, event.label) && Objects.equals(photos, event.photos);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, label, photos);
}
}
```

Photo Service:

```
@Service
public class PhotoService {

@Autowired
private PhotoRepository photoRepository;


public List<Photo> findAllPhotosOrderedByDate() {
    return photoRepository.findAllByOrderByDateAsc();
}

public void deletePhoto(long id) {
    Photo photo = photoRepository.findById(id).get();
    photoRepository.delete(photo);
}

public void savePhoto(Photo photo){
    photoRepository.save(photo);
}

public Photo getPhotoById(long id){
    return photoRepository.findPhotoById(id);
}

@Transactional
public void assignEvent(Photo photo, long id){
    photo.assignEvent(eventRepository.findById(id).get());
    photoRepository.save(photo);
}
```

Event Service:

```
@Service
public class EventService {

@Autowired
private EventRepository eventrepository;

@Autowired
private PhotoRepository photoRepository;


public List<Event> showEvents() {
    return eventrepository.findAll();
}

public void saveEvent(Event event) {
    eventrepository.save(event);
}

public void deleteEvent(long id) {
    Event deletedEvent = eventrepository.findById(id).get();

    for (Photo photo : deletedEvent.getPhotos()){
        photo.assignEvent(null);
        photoRepository.save(photo);
    }

    eventrepository.delete(deletedEvent);
}

public Event getEventById(long id){
    return eventrepository.findById(id).get();
}
}
```

Photo Controller:

```
@Controller
public class PhotoController {

    @Autowired
    private PhotoService photoService;

    @Autowired
    private EventService eventService;

    @GetMapping("/photo/upload/{id}")
    public String uploadPhoto(Model model, @PathVariable long id){
        Photo photo = new Photo();
        model.addAttribute("photo", photo);
        model.addAttribute("id", id);
        return "uploadPhoto";
    }

    @PostMapping("/photo/upload/{id}") 
         public String uploadPhoto(@ModelAttribute ("photo") Photo photo, @PathVariable long id){
    photoService.assignEvent(photo, id);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Index html for getting the specific Event-ID when clicking upload button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Photo Upload</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand"> <img src="/images/sticker.webp" width="50" height="50" alt="An image of Bloome">
            <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1 fs-3 align-middle">Bloome Fursuit Photographies</span>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/event/add"><p class="text-light bg-primary m-2 p-2">Create new event</p></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <br/>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h1>List of events</h1>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead class="table-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Label</th>
                    <th scope="col">Number of photos</th>
                    <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr th:each = "event : ${events}">
                    <th scope="row" th:text = "${event.label}"></th>
                    <td th:text = "${event.photos.size}"></td>
                    <td>
                        <a th:href="@{/photo/upload/{id} (id=${event.id})}" class="btn btn-primary">Upload photo</a>
                        <a th:href="@{/event/delete/{id} (id=${event.id})}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete event</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Photo html form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Upload photo</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <br/>
        <div class="container">
            <form th:action = "@{/photo/upload/{id} (id=${id})}" th:object="${photo}" method = "POST">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="labelPhoto" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Label</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg rounded-pill" id="labelPhoto" th:field = "*{label}" placeholder="Enter label">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="photographer" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Photographer</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg rounded-pill" id="photographer" th:field = "*{photographer}" placeholder="Enter photographer">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill m-2 p-2 align-text-top">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am passing the Event-ID through the GET and the POST-Endpoint of the Photo controller that I can assign there the Event to the photo. As far as I checked it the right ID arrives at "/photo/upload/{id}". I don't know why it seems there is no new photo created but instead the only existing gets altered since I don't reference the existing one when clicking on the upload button.

Comment: For starters don't use `@Data` for entities, that is a bad idea, it generates a wrong `equals`/`hashCode` and `toString` for JPA managed entities. Second implement a proper `equals`/`hashCode`. Next your `assignEvent` is wrong, you should also add the `photo` to the list in `Event`. When deleting you should also remove the `photo` from the list in event. And what you are doing in your controller (the 2 calls to the `photoService` should be 1 service call as that is the use case you are trying to do (and it should all be ok or not). I suggest move the `save` to the `assignEvent` method.

Comment: Okay, that was very constructive cuz I learnt something by it. But it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: What have you changed? Show it in your question.

Comment: Edited the code in question. I removed the @Data and generated getters and setters instead. Modified the assignEvent method to add the photo to the list in Event. Modified the PhotoController as well that it doesn't call the photoService twice and photo gets saved in the assignEvent instead. It's still updating the only existing photo instead of creating a new (additional) one. I already tried first creating several photos and then assign them to the event per passing id of event and photo via GET using path variabeles and that worked well. Why doesn't it work with current controller method..

Comment: Okay, there is definitely something strange going on in that application. I created 3 events. I can only add more than one photo to event number 3 (!). Event 1 and 2 stay at one photo. Every other event after 3 that I create can hold only one photo again. And the strangest thing is: it removes the photo from Event 3. So if Event 3 has 5 photos and I add the first and only photo to Event number 4 Event 3 will have 4 photos remaining.

Comment: Make sure you have a proper `equals`/`hashCode` (see https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/), also make sure you are setting the `cascadeType` on the `ManyToOne` to `ALL` so that the even gets properly saved (and you manage the direction of the relation on both sides). The call to `eventService.getEventById(id)` should be in the `assignEvent` method as well, you should just pass the id. Make sure that the `assignEvent` method is transactional.

Comment: Implemented equals/hashCode in Event and Photo, added the cascadeType moved the eventService.getEventById(id) to the assignEvent method. That all removed the wacky behavior I decribed before. Now it's back that I can only assign one photo per event. But still no more. If I put the @Transactional at the assignEvent method in PhotoService it doesn't change the behavior. Rather I can't delete the Events by using the button anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.

**Solution:**

```
@PostMapping("/photo/upload/{id}")
public String uploadPhoto(@ModelAttribute ("photo") Photo photo, @PathVariable long id){
    Photo newPhoto = new Photo();
    newPhoto.setLabel(photo.getLabel());
    newPhoto.setPhotographer(photo.getPhotographer());
    photoService.assignEvent(newPhoto, id);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

I had to modify the PostMapping method. Creating there a new Photo object as well and assign the values from the Photo object I got from the form.